# useEffect returns the whole HTML page

Tags: reactjs, django

This React component is returning the HTML page in the `blog` object.

if i add `{blog}` to the return it will return raw HTML, but won't take, `{blog.title}` for ie.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


const BlogDetail = (props) => {
    
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({})

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const slug = props.match.params.id;
            const fetchData = async () => {

                try {

                    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/blog/${slug}`);
                    setBlog(res.data);

                } catch (err) {

                }
            
            };

            fetchData();
        }, [props.match.params.id]);

        const createBlog = () => {
            return {__html: blog.body}
        }

    return (
        <div className='container mt-3'>
            <h1 className='display-2'>{blog.title}</h1>
            <h2 className='text-muted mt-3'>{blog.category}</h2>
            <div className='mt-5 mb-5' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createBlog()} />
            <hr />
            <p className='lead mb-5'>
                <Link to='/blog' className='font-weight-bold'>Back to Blog</Link>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears this happens because you are setting blog to `response.data` therefore, when you try to access `blog.body` you get the body of the `HTML` page but just because the body of the response your request is getting back  is the `HTML` page itself

Maybe a better option would be to have your html contain the classes for styling on your server, and just get that and put in in your `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: Not sure to understand your suggestion